# mysql insert only part of string value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

**MySql (MariaDB) insert in TEXT field only part of string file content.**

5.5.52-MariaDB-lubuntu0.14.04.1

File content:

```
1,"NODAÏA 01",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
2,"NODAÏA 02",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
3,"NODAÏA 03",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
....
```

**MySQL insert only:**

```
1, "NODA
```

Nothing more in this field.

**Cut where this symbol is: Ï**

**Why?**

Laravel send full file content to mysql.

Mysql Query log.:

> 93 Execute    insert into `tracking_parsed_data` (`cash_register_id`,
>   `api_id`, `command_id`, `data_type`, `report_timestamp_first`,
>   `report_timestamp_last`, `received_data`, `parsed_data`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values ('1356', '0', '0', '1', '20160919140001', NULL,
>   '1,\"NODAÏA 01\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n2,\"NODAÏA
>   02\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n3,\"NODAÏA
>   03\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n4,\"NODAÏA
>   04\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n5,\"NODAÏA
>   05\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n6,\"NODAÏA
>   06\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n7,\"NODAÏA
>   07\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n8,\"NODAÏA
>   08\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n9,\"NODAÏA
>   09\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n10,\"NODAÏA
>   10\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n11,\"NODAÏA
>   11\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n12,\"NODAÏA
>   12\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n13,\"NODAÏA
>   13\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n14,\"NODAÏA
>   14\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n15,\"NODAÏA
>   15\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n16,\"NODAÏA
>   16\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n17,\"NODAÏA
>   17\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n18,\"NODAÏA
>   18\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n19,\"NODAÏA
>   19\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n20,\"NODAÏA
>   20\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n21,\"NODAÏA
>   21\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n22,\"NODAÏA
>   22\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n23,\"NODAÏA
>   23\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n24,\"NODAÏA
>   24\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n25,\"NODAÏA
>   25\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n26,\"NODAÏA
>   26\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n27,\"NODAÏA
>   27\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n28,\"NODAÏA
>   28\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n29,\"NODAÏA
>   29\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n30,\"NODAÏA
>   30\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n31,\"NODAÏA
>   31\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n32,\"NODAÏA
>   32\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n33,\"NODAÏA
>   33\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n34,\"NODAÏA
>   34\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n35,\"NODAÏA
>   35\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n36,\"NODAÏA
>   36\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n37,\"NODAÏA
>   37\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n38,\"NODAÏA
>   38\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n39,\"NODAÏA
>   39\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n40,\"NODAÏA
>   40\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n41,\"NODAÏA
>   41\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n42,\"NODAÏA
>   42\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n43,\"NODAÏA
>   43\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n44,\"NODAÏA
>   44\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n45,\"NODAÏA
>   45\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n46,\"NODAÏA
>   46\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n47,\"NODAÏA
>   47\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n48,\"NODAÏA
>   48\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n49,\"NODAÏA
>   49\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n50,\"NODAÏA 50\",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\r\n',
>   NULL, '2016-09-26 15:46:09', '2016-09-26 15:46:09')

**If i this insert query run i mysql workbench, all works fine.**

Comment: See the discussion of "truncate" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a key to compare different records, then I yet did the following.

```
$fileContent = mb_convert_encoding($fileContent, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

Now ->

```
1,"NODA?A 01",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
2,"NODA?A 02",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
3,"NODA?A 03",0.00,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
...
```

and with this i can work. For now.

Comment: Do not use any conversion routine, that only adds to the problem.